# Can't restart podman container

Tags: redhat, process, containers, podman

I have installed a mtproto-proxy container:

```
# podman container list
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                     COMMAND               CREATED       STATUS             PORTS                        NAMES
02e39044364c  docker.io/telegrammessenger/proxy:latest  /bin/sh -c /bin/b...  8 months ago  Up 11 minutes ago  1.2.3.4:443->443/tcp  mtproto-proxy
```

But I can't restart it without a `SIGKILL`

```
# podman restart mtproto-proxy
WARN[0010] StopSignal SIGTERM failed to stop container mtproto-proxy in 10 seconds, resorting to SIGKILL
12345678904c0b38013c7d1c5db885e2646df1282dce25dc21a14256229807c7
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Without logs, you won't have answers

`podman logs -f mtproto-proxy`

Comment: `# podman logs -f mtproto-proxy
Error: using --follow with the journald --log-driver but without the journald --events-backend (file) is not supported`